# Maximize and NMaximize in comparison

Tags: mathematical-optimization

If on one hand:

```
N@Maximize[{Sqrt[y^2 - x^2], x + y^2 == 0 && 0 < y < 2 && -y < x < y}, {x, y}]
```

> {0.5, {x -> -0.5, y -> 0.707107}}

which is what is desired, on the other hand:

```
NMaximize[{Sqrt[y^2 - x^2], x + y^2 == 0 && 0 < y < 2 && -y < x < y}, {x, y}]
```

produces a warning:

> NMaximize::nrnum: The function value 4.15623 -1.34058 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {-1.35352,0.186697}.

and a consequent incorrect result:

> {0.285088, {x -> -0.681805, y -> 0.739008}}

I can't understand why this behavior. Could you explain it to me? Thank you!

Comment: `NMaximize[{Sqrt[y^2 - x^2]^2, y^2 - x^2 >= 0, 
  x + y^2 == 0 && 0 < y < 2 && -y < x < y}, {x, y}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sqrt` isn't handled properly by `NMaximize`, I think.

Workaround

```
NMaximize[{Sqrt@RealAbs[y^2 - x^2], x + y^2 == 0 && 0 < y < 2 && -y < x < y}, {x, y}]
(*{0.5, {x -> -0.5, y -> 0.707107}}*)
```

gives the  expected result.